# angular pop up not working in html script

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have two date pickers and i want to have this java script that checks the date and displays a popup box message if they put in a non usable date. However I can not get it to work.

```
<md-dialog-content>
    <div class="md-dialog-content">
      <md-datepicker input submit-required="true" ng-model="ctrl.minDate" md-placeholder="Enter Start Date"></md-datepicker>

      <md-datepicker input submit-required="true" ng-model="ctrl.maxDate" md-placeholder="Enter End Date"></md-datepicker>

  <script>


            if(new Date() < ctrl.minDate)
            {
                this.$window.alert("WARNING! Your start date can't be in the future. This will yield no search results.");
            }
            if(ctrl.maxDate < ctrl.minDate)
            {
                this.$window.alert("WARNING! Your end date can't be before your start date. This will yield no search results.");
            }
</script>

    </div>
  </md-dialog-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need ng-change in datepicker, when date changes ng-change function will invoke and check if date is valid

```
<md-datepicker input submit-required="true" ng-model="ctrl.minDate" ng-change="ctrl.isValid()" md-placeholder="Enter Start Date"></md-datepicker>

function isValid(){
  //your validation code
}
```